# Apache CXF impact when jvm upgrade from jdk 8 to jdk 17

Tags: java, spring, soap-client, java-17

I am migrating my micro services from jdk8 to jdk 17. As part of the migration, spring cloud and spring boot dependencies have been updated from 2.0 to 3.1.

I have a soap client to access from the rest API and the soap client is built using Apache CXF with crypto.
I am facing issues making the soap client call as the client is not invoking the service using the generated code from CXF.

Does CXF need any changes when the jvm is migrated from 8 to 17 ?

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generate-sources</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<sourceRoot>target/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
<wsdlOptions>
<wsdlOption>                                    <wsdl>/src/main/resources/wsdl/Test.wsdl</wsdl>                                 <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/Test.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
</wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>wsdl2java</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>`
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to identify the cause of the soap client failure. Apache CXF needs the jaxws-rt or the jax-ws-ri dependency explicitly in order to make a soap call after JDK 11. Pre JDK 11, Apache CXF provided the jaxws classes (HttpClientTransport) as part of CXF dependencies.

The solution for the problem is to include jaxws-rt and jaxws-ri dependencies for runtime and that resolved my issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I added the the dependency at runtime in my maven pom but got the same error